# Can we use pure Bootstrap with React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I would like to convert websites from PSD prototype to HTML/CSS/Bootstrap and then move on to JavaScript development and using React.js and some JavaScript coding.

Is it possible to use pure Bootstrap with React.js without using React-Bootstrap?

Also is it possible HTML/CSS Freelancer to do React-Bootstrap as a mockup only and then find a JavaScript developer to do the advance work like React.js and JS development?

I would like to develop app for Desktop using Electron and Hybrid App using same code base as possible.

Comment: Overall yes, some of the DOM stuff like modals might give you some issues. But as long as the className in your JSX = boostrap classnames you should be good

Comment: @erichardson30 Is it possible to find CSS/HTML Developer to do React-Bootstrap coding (PSD to React-Bootstrap - just mockup) and then find JavaScript developer to do React.js and JS development?

Comment: It's doable but you'll have write components yourself. And why do this if you can have a "clickable" prototype with React-Bootstrap?

Comment: I've built an app with electron before and since it's essentially a node app, if you pull the electron configuration out of it, it will run like a normal webapp. Electron essentially is using chromium (what powers chrome) to run the application. So there isn't much difference between electron and a normal react app except for the electron configuration. React-bootstrap is just a wrapper around bootstrap, so if the html/css dev created a mockup using bootstrap the JS dev should be able to mimic it exactly with react-bootstrap if needed

Answer (score 10):

In theory, yes. Since ReactComponent render themselves as html, you can just put the right css classes and there you go. That's totally fine for the css part of bootstrap.

**BUT**, all the javascript stuff done by the bootstrap library that modify the DOM will be in "conflict" with the virtual DOM of React.
One way to avoid that is to never rerender a react component for which its inner html is modified by bootstrap (by setting `shouldComponentUpdate() { return false }`).
Doing this way, you can think of React as just a template library to generate some HTML markup, and letting bootstrap actively modify this markup for you but's it's not what React is made for.

The whole point of React is the ability to see your UI as a function of your state : `view = f(state)` at any given moment.
That's why `react-bootstrap` reimplements all DOM modifications in a React way.

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can. I will include the bootstrap css as a CDN and go with the normal development.